# How can I find what the command window that occasionally pops up in Windows 8.1 for a fraction of a second is?

Tags: windows-8.1

Every few days I notice a command window open up automatically on my 2015 Dell XPS13 laptop.  It disappears within a fraction of a second, then comes back again very briefly and goes again.

Any idea what this is?

Any way for me to determine what it is?

I keep my computer relatively clean and typically install only those (reputable) programs that I know/use every day for work.  Gimp, Navicat, putty, WinSCP, Office, etc.

Possibilities:  Avira antivirus?  Garmin Express?  Java?  Windows itself?  Something Dell related?

Thanks

Comment: I take it you have looked at the jobs queue in Task Scheduler.

Comment: get a screen recorder program and pause it to see. Or try videoing the screen with your smartphone

Comment: Thank Chenmunka - put that as an answer and I'll accept it.  The culprit was "Dell SupportAssistAgent Auto Update", found in Scheduled Tasks as you suggested.

Comment: **Any idea what this is?** - It is the result of something be configured to be launched when your user profile is logged into more then likely.  As what specifically it is, we cant identify something, based on that description.

Comment: Support Assistant is the Dell software you can run to get the latest updates for your Dell, such as drivers, this software is hitting the dell servers to see if you have the latest version available installed on your PC and would offer an update if you didn't.